# Line separator conflict

Tags: git, android-studio, gradle

Usually, I prefer to work with the console version of Git, but it is first time I init Git on Android Studio project, so I just don't know what files I should commit and which to ignore, so that's why I chose GUI.

The 'problem' comes with the file gradlew.bat (I don't sure what does it for) it was committed with the entire project, but after the commit, it has shown as a modified staged file; Then I tried to amend it, UI displays `Contents have differences only in line separators`. So committed version uses LF line separators and local staged uses CRLF.

So what I have to do to finally commit it away from staged area?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"commit it away from staged area"_?

Comment: I suppose to amend it to make it part of the initial commit, but it instead sits in staged area. I get this error "0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: fix. warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in gradlew.bat. The file will have its original line endings in your working directory."

Comment: `.bat` sounds like a batch file for Windows CMD, so it probably *should* have CRLF termination. If a committed version has LF-only but should have CRLFs, you (or someone) should probably add a new commit with a corrected version. If your `.gitattributes` is set up correctly—it sounds like it is—this will also stop the complaints you're seeing. Note that the incorrect commit remains, forever(ish), because the *goal* of a version control system is to keep everything forever. There are ways to remove a bad commit but this is where things get tricky...

Comment: ... since this is a *new* project, though, presumably no one else has a clone of this new repo yet. In this case, after correcting the problem, you can (from the command line) run `git rebase -i --root` and squash the fixing-.BAT-file commit into the initial commit.